# Java strange unexpected IndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have the following function within a large project:

```
private void evalLinear(float w1, float I, int axis) {
    try{
        for (i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {

                wv[axis][i] = wrr1[axis] - W * x[i] / L;
                wm[axis][i] = (float) (wmm1[axis] + wrr1[axis] * x[i] - 0.5 * W * x[i] * x[i] / L);
                wy[axis][i] = (float) (1. / (6. * E * I) * (wrr1[axis]* Math.pow(x[i], 3.) - 3. * -wmm1[axis] * x[i] * x[i] - W / 4. * Math.pow(x[i], 4) / L));
                wd[axis][i] = (float) (1. / (6. * E * I) * (wrr1[axis] * 3 * Math.pow(x[i], 2.) - 6. * -wmm1[axis] * x[i] - W / 4. * 4 * Math.pow(x[i], 3.) / L));
        }
    }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        p.println("numPoints="+numPoints);
        p.println("i="+i+", IndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

It is run twice and throws the following error:

```
numPoints=7
i=2IndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
numPoints=7
i=7IndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
```

I don't understand in the first place how i can get an `IndexOutOfBounds` when `i=2` being `numPoints=7`, and then i can't understand how `i<numPoints` can take value `7`.

EDIT

Here is the complete StackTrace

```
axis:0, wy.length:2
i:7, wy[axis].length:7
axis:0, wy.length:2
i:7, wy[axis].length:7
numPoints=7
i=7, IndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at BeamCalc.Element.evalLinear(Element.java:441)
    at BeamCalc.Element.evalWeight(Element.java:345)
    at BeamCalc.LoadInterface$5.actionPerformed(LoadInterface.java:137)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(JTextField.java:492)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(JTextField.java:705)
    at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(JTextField.java:820)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1639)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2851)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2886)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2814)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6066)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4652)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1850)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:712)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:990)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:855)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:676)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4524)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:644)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:603)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:601)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:617)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:615)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:614)
```

Comment: what is numpoints? an array a list? I think you forgott .length or .size in your for loop in the question.

Comment: sorry numPoints is a class attribute (integer), its value is fixed to 7 and i have traced it all the way, it is always 7

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace();` to the catch block to figure out which line causes exception.

Comment: I see about 25 different places in that block that might be producing `IndexOutOfBoundsException` -- everywhere there are square brackets. The stack trace might help you.

Comment: Well you have `for` loop inside the `try-catch` and not vice versa so it will stop as soon as an exception is thrown. Also, `numPoints` seems to be per-defined which I can't see changing inside this snippet so it's value will remain same.

Comment: ok will add `e.printStackTrace();` and check...

Comment: The error is thrown at `at BeamCalc.Element.evalLinear(Element.java:440)` which is the line containing `wy[axis][i] = ...` but some times some other line within the for loop is throwing the exception..

Comment: the problem is not with `i` it is with `axis`... Add a check on the first line of your method: `if (axis >= numPoints) .... (throw an exception or just return or print a message or whatever)`.

Comment: I have also put the try catch inside the for loop and it throws the same excepion error

Comment: I dont think the error is with the `axis` because axis only has values `0` and `1`, plus the `i` is taking value 7 which should never do because `i<numPoints` and `numPoints=7`

Comment: This code being horrible and unreadable does not help with debugging

Comment: however horrible the code might be, i cant understand how `i` can take the same value as the for loop limit. `i=numPoints` when the limit of the loop is `i<numPoints` !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK ... so lets work it out.

```
wv[axis][i] = wrr1[axis] - W * x[i] / L;
wm[axis][i] = (float) (wmm1[axis] + wrr1[axis] * x[i] - 
    0.5 * W * x[i] * x[i] / L);
wy[axis][i] = (float) (1. / (6. * E * I) * 
    (wrr1[axis]* Math.pow(x[i], 3.) - 3. * 
     -wmm1[axis] * x[i] * x[i] - W / 4. * 
     Math.pow(x[i], 4) / L));
wd[axis][i] = (float) (1. / (6. * E * I) * 
    (wrr1[axis] * 3 * Math.pow(x[i], 2.) - 6. * 
     -wmm1[axis] * x[i] - W / 4. * 4 * Math.pow(x[i], 3.) / L));
```

No exception in the first statement implies `wv[axis][i]`, `wrr1[axis]` and `x[i]` are OK.

No exception in the second statement implies `wm[axis][i]` and `wmm1[axis]` are also OK.

Exception in third statement implies that the problem is on the LHS; i.e. `wy[axis][i]` is at fault.

That means that either `axis >= wy.length` or `i >= wy[axis].length`.

Now you need to figure which of those is the problem, and why it is occurring.

---

**UPDATE**

But then this: you say that you are getting this output from the catch block:

```
numPoints=7
i=7IndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
```

That is seemingly *impossible*.  The `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception is thrown within the loop (you say) and yet `i` is NOT less than `numPoints`.  And you don't change either `i` or `numPoints` withing the loop.

Are you showing us the real code, or has it been "sanitized"?

---

**UPDATE 2**

I see why we are getting confused.  <strike>The `i` you are printing in the catch block is NOT the loop variable.  The loop variable is out of scope at that point.  You must be printing a field of the enclosing class, or something!</strike>  Actually, even worse!  The loop is not *declaring* the variable `i` at all ... so we have a loop variable that is a field of the enclosing class, and that is potentially shared with other methods and / or other threads.  NASTY!

And `numPoints` is not a local variable either, so *that* could being changed too.

Comment: let me check both...

Comment: I get this `axis:1, wy.length:2` `i:7, wy[axis].length:7` So the problem is with the `i`. But i cant understand how i can take the same value as the for loop limit. `i==numPoints` when the limit of the loop is `i<numPoints` !?

Comment: I know, im going crazy, this what im showing is the real code, exactly copy pasted from the original. It belongs to a large project so perhaps there is something interfering but it also seems totally impossible to me.

Comment: Ok, let me check that too... i have just edited the question to add the complete StackTrace in case it may be of any help

Comment: ohhh can't believe it, you are right, `i` is actually a class attribute! Why would someone do that!? Im working on someone else's code... would there be a logical reason why he would do this? >> `int i; // Variable for loops`

Comment: Like @AdriaanKoster said, this code is horrible.  When someone writes code as horrible as this, questions like *"what is the logical reason for XXX"* tend to be irrelevant.

Comment: I have changed this line and now it works fine `for (int j = 0; j < numPoints; j++) {` Thanks a lot...

Comment: Well, im not so pro, so i guess i just wanted to hear a confirmation that "Yes, using a class attribute `i` for all the loops is a terrible thing"

Comment: Well, you heard it from me!

Comment: : ) haha, well i feel better now!